# Best practices for managing multiple language code in same repository

Tags: github, version-control, repository

Currently, I am working on an application which uses 3 programming languages. Now our company is using Mercurial based version control system.
We expect to go with git base system ( most probably we have to go with Azure 
DevOps Repos).

- Java : Server application and stand-alone application
- C# : windows application
- Sencha framework(Ext Js) : web front end

Currently,
we are managing all the code in the same repository because it is easy to manage the versions. We build applications manually(No any build tool).

When we are using git base system(Azure DevOps Repos),
**What is the best practice of managing these kinds of situations?**

Comment: code is code. the language does not matter

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the monorepo approach.
there are [good reasons to do so](https://medium.com/@adamhjk/monorepo-please-do-3657e08a4b70)), considering its content is text-based (code in different language.

> The default behavior of a polyrepo is isolation — that’s the whole point.
>   The default behavior of a monorepo is shared responsibility and visibility — that’s the whole point

The trade-offs coming with a Git monorepo won't be different than the ones with a Mercurial monorepo.